# map reduce program is not able to load csv file hbase table

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

i am running this command to load csv file using map-reduce program. 
it is running successfully but when scanning hbase table gives 0 rows.
Following is the console log data of the execution process:

```
  [hadoop@01HW394491 ~]$ HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hbase classpath' hadoop jar Desktop/bulk.jar /user/hadoop/3.csv /user/hadoop/load bulk
        13/06/07 15:59:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-cdh3u1--1, built on 07/18/2011 15:17 GMT
        13/06/07 15:59:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=01HW394491
        13/06/07 15:59:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_0
        13/06/07 15:59:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
        13/06/07 15:59:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre
        hbase.mapreduce.inputtable
        13/06/07 15:59:00 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
        13/06/07 15:59:02 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=172.29.179.59:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
        13/06/07 15:59:02 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /172.29.179.59:2181
        13/06/07 15:59:02 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 01HW394491/172.29.179.59:2181, initiating session
        13/06/07 15:59:02 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 01HW394491/172.29.179.59:2181, sessionid = 0x13f1e28c4b4000a, negotiated timeout = 180000
        13/06/07 15:59:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306071546_0001
        13/06/07 15:59:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
        13/06/07 15:59:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
        13/06/07 15:59:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201306071546_0001
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 21
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=5499
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=1
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=7561
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=159
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=63
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=127600
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=6
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=63
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=172.29.179.59:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /172.29.179.59:2181
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 01HW394491/172.29.179.59:2181, initiating session
        13/06/07 15:59:19 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 01HW394491/172.29.179.59:2181, sessionid = 0x13f1e28c4b4000c, negotiated timeout = 180000
        13/06/07 15:59:19 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Skipping non-directory hdfs://01HW394491:9000/user/hadoop/load/_SUCCESS
```

This is the Driver class having all configuration.
I am running this program in distributed mode.
i am using cloudera cdh3u1 version for running this program.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;



/**
 * HBase bulk import example<br>
 * Data preparation MapReduce job driver
 * <ol>
 * <li>args[0]: HDFS input path
 * <li>args[1]: HDFS output path
 * <li>args[2]: HBase table name
 * </ol>
 */

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        //conf.set("hbase.table.name", "bulk");
        conf.set("hbase.mapreduce.inputtable", args[2]);

        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","172.29.179.59");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        //conf.set("hbase.master", "172.29.179.59:60000");
        //conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","ibm-r1-node2.apache-nextgen.com");
        HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(conf);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "HBase Bulk Import Example");
        job.setJarByClass(HBaseKVMapper.class);


        job.setMapperClass(HBaseKVMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(KeyValue.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TableInputFormat.class);

        HTable hTable = new HTable(args[2]);

        // HTable hTable = new HTable("bulkdata");

        // Auto configure partitioner and reducer
        HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        /*
         * FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new
         * Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/685536/input1.csv"));
         * 
         * FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new
         * Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/685536/outputs12348"));
         * 
         */
         System.out.println(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        // Load generated HFiles into table
        LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf);
        loader.doBulkLoad(new Path(args[1]), hTable);

        // loader.doBulkLoad(new
        // Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/685536/outputs12348"), hTable);
    }
}
```

This is the class where i am inserting the value in hbase table,
create the simple table using command create 'bulk', 'fields'.
while scanning the data output is not showing.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

/**
 * HBase bulk import example
 * <p>
 * Parses Facebook and Twitter messages from CSV files and outputs
 * <ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>.
 * <p>
 * The ImmutableBytesWritable key is used by the TotalOrderPartitioner to map it
 * into the correct HBase table region.
 * <p>
 * The KeyValue value holds the HBase mutation information (column family,
 * column, and value)
 */
public class HBaseKVMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue> {

    final static byte[] SRV_COL_FAM = "fields".getBytes();
    String tableName = "";
    ImmutableBytesWritable hKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable();
    KeyValue kv;

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        Configuration c = context.getConfiguration();

        tableName = c.get("hbase.mapreduce.inputtable");
    }

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String fields[] = { "", "", "", "", "", "" };

        String field = value.toString();

        fields = field.split(",");
        String fieldValue = fields[1];
        FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
        String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
        hKey.set((filename).getBytes());

        for(int i=2 ; i<fields.length ; i++){
            fieldValue = fieldValue.concat(","+fields[i])  ;    
        }

        //fieldValue = fieldValue.substring(0,(fieldValue.length())-2);
        System.out.println(fieldValue);

        kv = new KeyValue(hKey.get(), SRV_COL_FAM, Bytes.toBytes(fields[0]),
                Bytes.toBytes(fieldValue));
        context.write(hKey, kv);

    }
}
```

this program is successfully executed in pseudo distributed mode.

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without looking at your code. Could you please do that?

Comment: This piece of output shows nothing and there is no point of putting this output here. This only shows, input file(s) is(are) seen and the program worked as you wrote the code and output is written to specified directory.

Comment: hi i added the code also.

Answer (score 0):

try HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hbase classpath' hadoop jar Desktop/bulk.jar /user/hadoop /user/hadoop/load bulk

I am not sure if MR takes exact input path FILE NAME. It probably expects path (folder path).

Comment: please check this program in your cluster.